# SVG expressions for linearGradient coordinates

Tags: svg

I am working with the following `linearGradient` element:

```
<linearGradient
   inkscape:collect="always"
   xlink:href="#linearGradient8704"
   id="linearGradient8774"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   x1="45%"
   y1="45%"
   x2="55%"
   y2="55%" />
```

Is it possible to somehow use basic expressions in the x/y coordinates?  I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
x1="50% - 20px",
y1="50% - 20px",
```

Comment: You might want to update the question to clarify that you need to use this in a CSS background image, since that rules out using javascript inside the svg. And that your target browser is Opera on the Nintendo Wii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you have to do it this way? Not to detract from your original question, but the coder inside me screams that using expressions with different units is wrong. Would it be possible to convert one of the values to the others units using javascript? Something like:

```
 var new_x1 = (window.innerWidth/2) + 20;
 document.getElementById('linearGradient8774').setAttribute('x1', new_x1 + 'px');
```

Comment: I am trying to better-approximate an inset effect.  You can see my original question at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/svg-downward-inner-bevel.  I'm making graphics for a web interface for a Nintendo Wii, which has no support for CSS3, but supports SVG background images for DIV elements.  I needed a box that was dynamically sized, but fixed border radius (done), and a border gradient that matched those fixed-size corners, for the effect to look right.  I don't know much about SVG... can I use JS in the SVG document itself?  Or does the JS run in my page hosting the SVG?

Comment: You can actually do both. If you have a page controlling the svg, I would recommend adding some scripting to that, otherwise, you can embed scripting tags, (or external files) into svg. (See here, near top: http://pilat.free.fr/english/routines/js_dom.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It might become possible to use calc() expressions (as defined in CSS) in presentation attributes in the future, but it's not yet part of any svg spec, and AFAIK there are no implementations at the moment that support this.

You might be able to get this working if you use inline svg and javascript for calculating the values you need and then place the svgs where you need them using CSS.